# How to Compile the below using GroovyWrapper?

Tags: groovy, compilation

Unfortunately my coding knowledge is limited and have Zero experience with GroovyWrapper.

Looking to compile the below:

https://github.com/rosstroha/traktor-key-converter

Comment: GroovyWrapper is part of that repo. Have you tried what the instructions tell you to do? Did that work? If not, what was the error?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so this program is pretty simple.  You don't need GroovyWrapper unless you want an executable jar file.  You can pretty much run this thing from an online groovy compiler.  I setup one you can look at.  You just need to upload your Traktor file (collection.nml) to the doodle using the file up arrow icon next to the execute button and you can run the code directly from [here](https://jdoodle.com/ia/J5s).

If you found this helpful please accept this as the answer.